# Jquery problem when adding multiple questions and its options - Clone

Tags: jquery

I wrote the following code that should:

1. Add Questions: As displayed in the image below should clone whole #1
2. Add options: As displayed in the image below should clone the whole #2

Somehow it's not working as expected so the additional options button disappears from the first question when you click on add questions button.

[image]

```js
 // add row
  $("#addRow").click(function() {
    var html = "";
    html += '<div id="inputFormRow">';
    html += '<div class="form-group">';
    html += '<label for="question">Enter Question</label>';
    html += '<textarea class="form-control" id="question" rows="3"></textarea>';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '<div class="input-group mb-3">';
    html += '<input type="text" name="options[]" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="Enter Option" autocomplete="off">';
    html += '<label for="select-options">OR - Select Options</label>';
    html += '<select class="form-control" id="select-options">';
    html += '<option value="">Select an option</option>';
    html += '<option value="strongly-agree">Strongly Agree</option>';
    html += '<option value="agree">Agree</option>';
    html += '<option value="neither-agree-nor-disagree">Neither Agree nor Disagree</option>';
    html += '<option value="disagree">Disagree</option>';
    html += '<option value="strongly-disagree">Strongly Disagree</option>';
    html += '<option value="not-applicable">Not Applicable</option>';
    html += '</select>';
    html += '<div class="input-group-append">';
    html += '<button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '</div>';

    $('#newRow').append(html);
  });
  

  // add row
  $("#addOptions").click(function() {
    var html = "";
    html += '<div id="inputFormRow">';
    html += '<div class="input-group mb-3">';
    html += '<input type="text" name="options[]" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="Enter Option" autocomplete="off">';
    html += '<label for="select-options">OR - Select Options</label>';
    html += '<select class="form-control" id="select-options">';
    html += '<option value="">Select an option</option>';
    html += '<option value="strongly-agree">Strongly Agree</option>';
    html += '<option value="agree">Agree</option>';
    html += '<option value="neither-agree-nor-disagree">Neither Agree nor Disagree</option>';
    html += '<option value="disagree">Disagree</option>';
    html += '<option value="strongly-disagree">Strongly Disagree</option>';
    html += '<option value="not-applicable">Not Applicable</option>';
    html += '</select>';
    html += '<div class="input-group-append">';
    html += '<button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '</div>';

    $('#newQuestion').append(html);
  });

  // remove row
  $(document).on('click', '#removeRow', function() {
    $(this).closest('#inputFormRow').remove();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popup Button -->
<label for="survey-name">Add Question below</label>
  <form method="post" action="">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
      <!-- Question -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="question">Enter Question</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="question" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        <!-- Options -->
        <div id="inputFormRow">
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
          
            <input type="text" name="options[]" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="Enter options" autocomplete="off">
            <label for="select-options"> -OR - Select an option</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="select-options">
            <option value="0">Select an option</option>
            <option value="strongly-agree">Strongly Agree</option>
            <option value="agree">Agree</option>
            <option value="neither-agree-nor-disagree">Neither Agree nor Disagree</option>
            <option value="disagree">Disagree</option>
            <option value="strongly-disagree">Strongly Disagree</option>
            <option value="not-applicable">Not Applicable</option>
            </select>
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="newRow"></div>
        <button id="addOptions" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Add Options</button><br> 
        <div id="newQuestion"></div>
        <button id="addRow" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Add Questions</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your problem is id's. An ID must be unique.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen which IDs?

Comment: Everytime you add a new row. the delete button has the id removeRow. And many more